# SQLite column information transfer with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I want to transfer a column of data from a CSV file into a column in a SQLite Database Table (Matches).

The CSV file (EPL13-14Data) details results from every match of the 2013-14 EPL Season. There is a "Hometeam" column that lists the name of the Hometeam for every match of the season. ---> EPL13-14Data.Hometeam

I have created a table (Teams) in the Database that assigns a unique TeamID (integer) to each team name. This "TeamID" column is the primary key --> Teams.TeamID

I have created a table (Matches) that provides reduced information for each match of the season. I have created a "HomeTeamID" column in the Matches table. ----> Matches.HomeTeamID

I want to transfer the HomeTeam column's information from the EPL13-14Data CSV file to the Matches table in the database, *but I want to input the unique TeamID that corresponds to the name of the team into the Matches table, NOT the name of the team itself. In the Matches table, the HomeTeamID column is a Foreign Key which corresponds to the Teams.TeamID column.

This is the conversion path I wish to execute

EPL13-14Data.Hometeam --> Teams.Name --> Teams.TeamID --> Matches.HomeTeamID

**SQLite3.0**

```
SELECT Teams.TeamID 
INTO Matches.HomeTeamID
FROM Teams
WHERE EPL_DATA.Hometeam = Teams.Name;
```

I get an error message when I attempt to run this code, not sure which SELECT ... INTO code to use or which INSERT ... SELECT code to use

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want neither but instead want to **UPDATE** the HomeTeamID column for the appropriate match.

So you want something along the lines of

```
UPDATE Matches 
  SET Matches.HomeTeamId = (SELECT Teams.TeamID FROM Teams WHERE EPL.DATA.Hometeam = Teams.Name) 
WHERE your_where_clause_to_identify_the respective_match_to_be_updated
```